# No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I'm following Devtiro's guide, but I encountered an error that I shouldn't have according to his guide.

I'm trying to connect Spring Boot to a database (H2) for the first time.

Here's the error:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl userTest] in constructor [public com.example.todolist.dao.impll.UserDaoImplIntegTest(com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl)]: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
 at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.ParameterResolutionDelegate.resolveDependency(ParameterResolutionDelegate.java:136)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:342)
 ... 3 more
```

Here's the code:

UserDaoImplIntegTest.java

```
package com.example.todolist.dao.impll;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl;
import com.example.todolist.TestDataUtil;
import com.example.todolist.User;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class UserDaoImplIntegTest {

    private UserDaoImpl userTest;

    @Autowired
    public UserDaoImplIntegTest(UserDaoImpl userTest) {
        this.userTest = userTest;
    }
    @Test
    public void testThatUserCanBeCreatedAndRecalled() {
        User user = TestDataUtil.createTestUser();
        userTest.create(user);
        Optional<User> result = userTest.find(user.getId());
        assertThat(result).isPresent();
        assertThat(result.get().getId()).isEqualTo(user.getId());
    }
    
}
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
package com.example.dao.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

import com.example.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.todolist.User;

@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public UserDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void create(User user) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO users (id, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", user.getId(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> find(Long id) {
        List<User> result = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1",
            new UserRowMapper(), 
            id
        );
        return result.stream().findFirst();
    }

    public static class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return User.builder()
            .id(rs.getLong("id"))
            .email(rs.getString("email"))
            .password(rs.getString("password"))
            .build();
        }

    }
}
```

UserDao.java

```
package com.example.dao;

import java.util.Optional;

import com.example.todolist.User;

public interface UserDao {
    
    void create(User user);

    Optional<User> find(Long id);
}
```

User.java

```
package com.example.todolist;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.application.name=todolist
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Thanks in advance!

Tried searching for the root of ParameterResolutionException as well as NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and their solutions, yet it didn't help with anything

I also analysed Devtiros github repository ([text](https://github.com/devtiro/course-spring-boot/tree/main/7_databases_sql/6_dao_create_read_int_test/database)), but that was no help either

Another thing I tried was moving the UserDaoImpl, UserDao and User classes to the same folder as the UserDaoImplIntegTest, yet it only gave me more errors at the end